# Problem with strptime() - %p is not taken into account

Tags: c++, parsing, datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert a date in a particular format using `strptime`, and i realized that the information about AM/PM is lost. Not sure why.

Here is the code.

```
struct tm t;
strptime("Wed 4/18/2007 4:28:22 PM", "%a %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p", &t);
std::cout<<t.tm_hour<<endl;
strptime("Wed 4/18/2007 4:28:22 AM", "%a %m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p", &t);
std::cout<<t.tm_hour<<endl;
```

Can anybody tell me whats the purpose of having the `%p` specifier in `strptime`?

Thanks in advance,
AJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is with `%H`, which will read the hour in **24-hour** format and ignore AM/PM. If you want to read the hour in **12-hour** format and make use of AM/PM use `%I` in place of `%H`.

You can refer to the manual [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html).

Answer (score 0):

From [this site](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html):

> %p = The locale's equivalent of a.m or p.m.